# Jfrog Xray: Unable to generate Security Report

Tags: jfrog-xray

I have setup a new instance of [jFrog-xray](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/XRAY) and configured artifacts. The "Security Report" button is not enabled. What do I need to do to ensure the button is enabled?

NOTE: The question is wrongly tagged since `jfrog-xray` is not an existing tag and mission-control is the closest (product from same company)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you will have some alerts and Xray will find some vulnerabilities the button will be available to you.